# SYMPY : Is it possible to perform symbolic approximation?

Tags: sympy

**Notice : This is a very simple example of what I would like to perform**

Suppose, I have the following sympy expression `(A-B)/(2*A)`.

Is it possible to indicate that A is much larger than B (`A>>B`) so the expression becomes `1/2` (or that B is much larger than A and so the expression becomes `-B/(2*A)`)?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a limit:

```
>>> from sympy import var, limit
>>> var("A B")
(A, B)
>>> eq = (A-B)/(2*A)
>>> limit(eq, A, oo)
1/2
```

In the case of wanting to apply the "adding or subtracting a large number" rule (as I called it in Chemistry for my students) then only terms with `B` in the sum survive. This can be handled, sum-wise as

```
>>> eq. replace(
... lambda x: x.is_Add and B in x.free_symbols,
... lambda x: x.as_independent(B)[1])
...
-B/(2*A)
```

Putting this into a helper function `big(what, where)` gives:

```
>>> big = lambda B, eq: eq.replace(
... lambda x: x.is_Add and B in x.free_symbols,
... lambda x: x.as_independent(B)[1])
>>> 
>>> big(A, eq)
1/2
>>> big(B, eq)
-B/(2*A)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I edited my post. Is there a solution with the second example ?

Comment: Probably in the more general case what is wanted comes from something like `series((A-B)/(2*A), A, oo, n=1).removeO()` or `series((A-B)/(2*A), B, oo, n=0).removeO()`.